# When pushing an update to a pre-existing Rails app on Digital Ocean Droplet using Capistrano, the deploy fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ssh, capistrano

I'm working on a Rails app that already exists inside a Digital Ocean droplet. The app is built using Capistrano to deploy to the remote server.

Originally it kept asking for a password when I would try to deploy the update, but after setting up the SSH access properly it now will try to deploy, but fail.

I'm not the original developer that built the app, but I do have SSH root access to the server. I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I had to insert my own SSH keys onto the server to get it to even try deploying in the first place.

When I try to

$cap production deploy

It begins all of the tasks to deploy to the droplet, runs for a while, then fails at this line:

failed: "env PATH=/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims:/home/deploy/.rbenv/bin:$PATH sh -c 'ls /var/www/apps/[APP_NAME]/shared/assets/.sprockets-manifest*'" on [IP_ADDRESS]

What's failing in Capistrano's tasks/processes, and how do I fix it? Is it not recognizing my local machine as authorized to push updates?

Comment: Does this path exists on the server : `/var/www/apps/[APP_NAME]/shared/assets/.sprockets-manifest*` ?

Comment: Yes! I'm not sure how to edit it so that the error stops being thrown however- any suggestions?